# Azure function deployed but never run on blob input

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

We are setting an Azure functions to be triggered once we have a file in an azure blob storage.

This file will be used as an input of a python script hosted on Github.

Here is the azure function basic script that was generated once the function was set using visual studio code:

import logging

import azure.functions as func

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

the aim is that, this TOML input file that was uploaded into the blob should serve as a loader of the variables.

The script then run and generates another file that would be saved in another blob.

Using a web app, we are able to load into the blob, however, the function is not triggered by looking at the monitor tab:

[image]

What we want is that within the main() of the azure function, to trigger a python project on github to run with the input file. so it becomes:

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    # python src/main.py fileInput.toml
```

Any idea why the enabled function is not running and what to add into it's function?

Comment: have you checked if the connection string to the storage account is correct and mapping to the correct container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and followed below process:

Firstly, created a function app and storage account.

Then in Configuration Section of Function App check if the Connection string is correct in `AzureWebJobsStorage`:

- Copied Connection string from Storage account here:

[image]

- And pasted here in function app:

[image]

Then create a blob function trigger:

[image]

Now in Function Trigger code:

```
 import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

Now in function.json check the conatiner name :

```
samples-workitems
```

[image]

Now create a container in storage account linked to Function app:

[image]

Then Upload the blob inside the container:

[image]

After Uploading the blob:

[image]
**Output:**

Check in Logs section Of Function app :

Now use below query to check the blob trigger is triggered or not:

```
traces
|where message contains "Python blob trigger function processed blob"
```

[image]

Comment: wow. thank you. my missing part then was the authentication.